# How to change map centre at certain window size for Google Maps Api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get a function to change the map centre when the browser is below 1104px, so far I have the map auto going to the centre on resize, but I require to actually define two different centres at different widow sizes due to a change in page layout.

Here is the code.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script> 
<script>

var map;

function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.522696, -0.107620);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.522403, -0.097636),
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        draggable: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    rotateControl:false,
    streetViewControl:false,
    overviewMapControl:false,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
                        mapOptions);

    var image = '<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/marker.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.522696, -0.107620);
    var officeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(myLatlng);
    }); 

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.body.offsetWidth` will give you the width of the viewport, set the center based on the value:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
 map.setCenter((document.body.offsetWidth<1104)
                    //<1104
                  ? latLng
                    //>=1104
                  : anotherLatLang
              );
});
//trigger the resize to get the initial center
google.maps.event.trigger(window, 'resize');
```